# How to test file system operations

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing

I have a method which synchronizes two folders, that looks like this:

```
void Synchronize(string folderAPath, string folderBPath)
{
    //Code to synchronize the folders
}
```

What would be the best way to test if the files were synchronized properly, or in general, test methods that manipulate the file system? Is there a way to set up virtual folders?

Comment: Consider using the Uri class instead of strings for the arguments in order to express your intent, as well as get some argument checking for free. MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could define an interface `IFileSystem` that provides file related methods and pass that into your `Synchronize` method. For the real system you implement the interface using real File I/O, for your testing you could pass an implementation that just operates in memory based on the test data your set up beforehand, but without touching the real file system.

There's by the way nothing wrong imo using tests that depend on the file system, especially if it would be very hard to fake the data expected by the method under test - while these tests could be considered "integration" kind of tests, as opposed to unit tests they still provide value.

Answer (score 8):

As @BrokenGlass already advised, hiding the actual API behind a mockable interface allows you to unit test your logic. I would do this only though if there is substantial logic in there to justify the extra complexity needed to make the interface unit testable. Testing that the code really works under real circumstances, on the real filesystem needs integration tests anyway, so in simple cases the unit tests could be skipped, to use one's limited resources more effectively.

Comment: +1 Agreed - sometimes the effort in setting up a "real" unit test is not worth it, it all depends on the scenario - pragmatism wins for me.

Comment: +1 In our current refactor I'm in the process of deleting hundreds of lines of (probably buggy) abstraction code and replacing lots of confusing IoC indirection with straight system calls.  It's been bloating our code base for the last year, used for unit testing about 25 lines of real code.  Seemed like a good idea at the time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a choice but to write a wrapper.

**EDIT: updated the link, It's a NuGet!**
Have a look at this one : http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2010/11/19/fluentpath-1-0.aspx

**EDIT**
Erg, just saw that the library I linked to does not have the extra abstraction layer to enable testing. *But hey, it's open source ;)*

Comment: You *do* have a choice. Please see my answer.

Comment: well, I see the point in an integration test that runs every night. But are you going top spin up a virtual machine locally after each change or each build?

Comment: No. We have a virtual machine set up for each system in development that needs filesystem testing. A snapshot is set up with a well known starting state. As part of the testing script, the snapshot is applied and the tests are run. It's a painless process, and fully automated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of testing file system operations. Just open the file, that way you can test with different data by opening a different file.

Answer (score -1):

I have used virtual machines on [Hyper-V](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753637(v=WS.10).aspx) in the past with great success. You can use [snapshots](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560637(v=ws.10).aspx) to create a known state and go back to it as many time as necessary for testing purposes. Other virtual machine technologies would probably work too.

We have a virtual machine set up for each system in development that needs filesystem testing. A snapshot has been set up as well as a well known starting state. As part of the testing script, the snapshot is applied and the tests are run. It's a painless process, and fully automated.

In our experience, this solution has proven to be superior to "fake" approaches such as simulating the file system, because it gives us the real-life, messy, unpredictable behaviour of file systems. Running out of space, permissions issues, RAID failures, reparse point problems, etc. are hard to simulate.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Who says? We have been using it for unit testing for over 3 years. Could you please explain why it's not an option in your opinion? Besides, the OP does not mention *unit* testing.

Comment: The tags include [unit-testing]. And of course you can use unittest tools with a VM but then it's not really unittesting anymore. With all that said, I still consider this a reasonable (pragmatic) answer to the problem.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to explain your downvote? You are not helping if you don't comment. Thank you.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Well, it is an answer straight from a 3-year experience. You may find it impractical, but it comes from practice. I find it quite arrogant that you boldly state that my answer is "hardly an option", when my team and I have been using it every day for 3 years!

Comment: But it's not (really) unittesting. And pragmatic != impractical.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Of course it is unit testing. In the same way that testing a unit that needs to insert a record on a database needs a database infrastructure in place. Can you point me to a definition of unit testing that our approach violates?

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Regarding pragmatic and impractical, I know what these words mean. :-) My point wasn't about these words, it was about your statement that my answer is "hardly an option" for unit testing. It's been a valid and successful option for us. Maybe it wouldn't be for you, but that does not invalidate it.

Comment: Just call it integration testing and we will be in agreement.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: Sorry, I can't agree with you as long as you keep saying that our proven approach is hardly an option. I don't care about the label you attach to it.